# Angular 2 firebase get email and uid error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I've done login/register with angular 2 firebase. Everything was fine, after a while I got error in every page when I am trying to get user profile.

```
 getProfile(){
    this.aFAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data.email && data.uid) {
        console.log("Prisijunges")
      }
      else {
        console.log("Neprisijunges")
      }

    })
  }
```

The thing is - console log should not show error if(data.email and data.uid is null) , it should use "else". But it never does.

Error in every page :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null
```

Why function only calls "if" statement but not else if email is null ?

Comment: It seems like `data` itself is null and you are trying to reference `email` of the null object `data`. Try `if(data && data.email && data.uid)`

Comment: Thank you it worked ! That's weird because a week ago it was working fine without data.

Comment: Oh then there seems to be an issue with your firebase API.

Comment: Yes maby - because only in app.component.ts i need to add data, in other pages I do not need to add it.

Comment: in home.component.ts : 
  getProfile(){
    this.aFAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data.email && data.uid) {
        console.log("Prisijunges")
        this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`)
      }
      else {
        console.log("Neprisijunges")
      }
    })
  }

Works just fine, dont even know why.